# sub-routines on Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, pdp-11

can I do something like this on Assembly  `bne jsr swap`, if not how can I solve this problem  from C, thanks in advance

```
if(start!=pivot_index){
  swap(board,start,pivot_index);
 }
```

I was taught that I must write `jsr` and `sub-routine` but can I do something like this `bne sub-routine`

Comment: pdp-11 but I'm working on windows, have simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In assembly that would usually be translated into something like this (pseudo-assembly):

```
load [start]
compare [pivot_index]
branch-if-equal label1
push [pivot_index]
push [start]
push [board]
call swap
add-stack-pointer 12
label1:
```

ie. the `if` statement is converted into a jump that jumps over the body of the `if` if the controlling expression is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do this. On x86 you need two branches:

```
  # assume EAX = start, EBX = pivot_index

  cmp eax, ebx
  beq .SkipSwap

  call swap

.SkipSwap:
```

For ARM assembly it's easier because you can use a conditional branch:

```
  # assume r0 = start, r1 = pivot_index

  cmp  r0, r1
  blne swap
```

Comment: sorry, but I'm workin on pdp-11 simulator, can I do the same thing?

Comment: well. For PDP11 take the x86 code, adjust the names of the registers and use jsr instead of call to jump.. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do `bne subroutine` instead of `jsr subroutine`, because `jsr` means "jump setting return".

The difference between that and the conditional branch instructions is that the `jsr` pushes the return address onto the stack, so the subroutine knows where to return. If you just branch to the subroutine using `bne`, there's no return address saved, so the subroutine doesn't know where to return when done.

caf's answer shows you the typical way you would handle that, you just need to translate it into PDP-11 operations.